# Tictactoe game Unexpected end of input expecting IF MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers, tic-tac-toe

I am creating a trigger for a tic-tac-toe game that checks whether the player or the computer won. I have it coded right, I believe, but at the end it says "syntax error, unexpected end_of_input, expecting IF" I have the delimiter coded right but that seems to be the problem. Here's the code:

```
 delimiter //
create trigger check_winner
after update on grid
for each row

begin
declare message varchar(100);

select A into @A1 from grid where ttt = 1;
select A into @A2 from grid where ttt = 2;
select A into @A3 from grid where ttt = 3;
select B into @B1 from grid where ttt = 1;
select B into @B2 from grid where ttt = 2;
select B into @B3 from grid where ttt = 3;
select C into @C1 from grid where ttt = 1;
select C into @C2 from grid where ttt = 2;
select C into @C3 from grid where ttt = 3;


-- Horizontal wins
    if @A1 = @B1 and @B1 = @C1 then     
        set message = concat('Player ', @A1, ' is victorious!');
        signal sqlstate '42000'
        set message_text = message;


   else if @A2 = @B2 and @B2 = @C2 then     
        set message = concat('Player ', @A2, ' is victorious!');
        signal sqlstate '42000'
        set message_text = message;


   else if @A3 = @B3 and @B3 = @C3 then     
        set message = concat('Player ', @A3, ' is victorious!');
        signal sqlstate '42000'
        set message_text = message;


-- Vertical wins
    else if @A1 = @A2 and @A2 = @A3 then     
        set message = concat('Player ', @A1, ' is victorious!');
        signal sqlstate '42000'
        set message_text = message;

    else if @B1 = @B2 and @B2 = @B3 then     
        set message = concat('Player ', @B1, ' is victorious!');
        signal sqlstate '42000'
        set message_text = message;

    else if @C1 = @C2 and @C2 = @C3 then     
        set message = concat('Player ', @C1, ' is victorious!');
        signal sqlstate '42000'
        set message_text = message;

-- Diagonal wins
    else if @A1 = @B2 and @B2 = @C3 then     
        set message = concat('Player ', @A1, ' is victorious!');
        signal sqlstate '42000'
        set message_text = message;

    else if @A3 = @B2 and @B2 = @C1 then     
        set message = concat('Player ', @A3, ' is victorious!');
        signal sqlstate '42000'
        set message_text = message;

-- Game continues
    else 
        set message = 'Game is still ongoing';
        signal sqlstate '42000'
        set message_text = message;

end if;

end// -- error is right here
```

any help given would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
else if
```

to

```
elseif
```

i.e. remove the space between the else and if.